# Magento 2 : Change Order Status From Pending to Pending Payment

Tags: magento2, admin, order-status

I want to change default order status from **Pending** to **Pending Payment** after customer place an order.

I have assign **Pending Payment** order status to **Pending**, and check **Use Order Status As Default** and **Visible On Storefront**.

But it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In admin page, go to **Stores > Configuration > Sales > Payment Method**, select your active payment method, and set **New Order Status** to Payment Method.
[image]

If you can't find Pending Payment from that select box, you need to assign Pending Payment order status to Pending.